# Scrapy - extract information from list of links

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am programming a scraper with python and scrapy .I have as start_urls a page that contains a list of products, my scraper gets the links of these products and scrape the information of each of the products (I save the information in the fields of the class items.py).  Each of these products can contain a list of variations, I need to extract information from all the variations and save them in a list field and then save this information in item['variations'].

```
def parse(self, response):
        links = response.css(css_links).getall()
        links = [self.process_url(link) for link in links]
        for link in links:
            link = urljoin(response.url, link)
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_product)

    def parse_product(self, response):
        items = SellItem()
        shipper = self.get_shipper(response)
        items['shipper'] = shipper
        items['weight'] = self.get_weight(response)
        items['url'] = response.url
        items['category'] = self.get_category(response)
        items['cod'] = response.css(css_cod).get()
        items['price'] = self.get_price(response)
        items['cantidad'] = response.css(css_cantidad).get()
        items['name'] = response.css(css_name).get()
        items['images'] = self.get_images(response)
        variations = self.get_variations(response)
        if variations:
            valid_urls = self.get_valid_urls(variations)
            for link in valid_urls:
                #I need to go to each of these urls and scrape information and then store it in the 
                 #variable items['variations'].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a 2nd method, call it "parse_details"

Then add callback=self.parse_details when you do "yield request" from your first method i.e. parse_product.

You can transfer the collected data between methods using "response.meta"

Scrapy covers it in the docs:

see : https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions

Also read about : "Request.cb_kwargs"